# Stacking column across 3d numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

How can I stack 2 arrays of shape ( 1,1024, 3) (1024, 616, 3)  column wise?
For the above example  resultant array should be (1025,616,3).

I was able to stack same shaped arrays (1, 1024, 3) (1024, 1024, 3)  using

```
 np.concatenate((x_cache,tile),axis=0)
 or
 np.vstack(x_cache,tile)
```

However I am unable to stack when the 2 arrays 2nd dimensions don't match. Similarly How can I do row stacking when the shape doesn't match.

Comment: Get rid of a lot of values from the first, changing the (1,1024,3) to (1,616,3).

Comment: Could you explain why I  should get rid of values when  I am just adding a extra column to 3 2d arrays?

Comment: You could concatenate a (1024,1,3) to (1024,616,3) to make a (1024, 617,3)  To me the math is simple 1+616=617.  1024+1=1025.  That's what's happening to the concatenated axis.  The others have to match and remain unchanged.  I don't know what else you imagine happening.

Comment: How do you expect to combine them to get that resultant shape? You could get (1024, 617, 3) by permuting the columns in the first array and stacking, but there are too many elements in the first array to get the shape you want.